# I can't hide/show some elements in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, hide, show

I have 3 "span"s

```
<span class="input1" style="display:block;"><span class="round"></span></span>
<span class="input2" style="display:none;"><span class="round"></span></span>
<span class="input3" style="display:none;"><span class="round"></span></span>
```

And this is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    act = 1;
    next = act+1;
    });

$(".round").click(function (){
         $('.input'+act).hide();
         $('.input'+next).show();
         act = next;
    });
```

Push ".round" for the first time -> ".input1" - hide & ".input2" - show
If i want to push ".round" for the second time -> nothing happened. (This is the problem)

How to hide ".input2" and show ".input3"?
Thanks for help and sorry for my english!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

Because `next` is always equal to 2.

The second time, `act == 2` and `next == 2` so you hide then show the same element.

Try that:

```
$('.round').click(function (){
    $('.input' + act).hide();
    $('.input' + next).show();
    act = next++;
});
```

---

## A bit of explanation

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators):

**`++`** is a increment operator.

> This operator increments (adds one to) its operand and returns a
> value. If used postfix, with operator after operand (for example,
> x++), then it returns the value before incrementing. If used prefix
> with operator before operand (for example, ++x), then it returns the
> value after incrementing.

Answer (score 2):

I probably wouldn't try and do it by specific classnames... use the DOM structure.

```
$(".round").click(function (){
   $(this).parent().hide().next().show();
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U7cYN/

Comment: @Purmou - woah, weird. Could be a jQuery bug to do with a span/inline-element being a parent element...

Comment: @Purmou - Actually, I have found the answer. `.closest()` begins with the current element, and as the current element is a `span`, it just hides itself.

Comment: Haha, that's pretty funny. Never knew that about `closest()`. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

This will work, on third click text will dispear from display:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    act = 1;
    next = act;
});

$(".round").click(function (){
     next++;
     $('.input'+act).hide();
     $('.input'+next).show();
     act = next;
});
```